# a way to point one bean to another in spring xml

Tags: xml, spring, separation-of-concerns

**Is there a way to point one bean to another using Spring XML SPring Expression Language (SPEL), other than aliasing?**  string4 below works using aliasing. But string3 does not.  string3 is not working because you can't put a value attrib in a bean tag.  But it's not a constructor-arg nor a parameter.  It is the thing itself.  What is the correct way to write string3?  Is there an spel way to write it?

The purpose is to create 2 beans, string1 and string2.  Could be other kinds of objects.  But String here to simplify the example.  Another object is going to ask for a bean by name, "string3". It has no knowledge of string1 or string2; only that it needs string3.  In the xml we can map string3 to either of string1 or string2, depending on the circumstances of a deployment.

E.g. On server 1 we point string3 to string 1 in the xml.  On server 2 we point string3 to string 2 in the xml.  It keeps the application from having to know if we need string1 or string2.  Only in the xml do we make that assignment. Preserve SoC.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="somePackage.SomeClass"/>

    <bean name="string1" id="string1" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="some string one"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="string2" id="string2" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="another string two"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="string3" id="string3" value="#{string1}"/>
    <!--
    <bean name="string3" id="string3" value="#{string2}"/>
    -->

    <!--
    <alias name="string2" alias="string4"/>
    -->
    <alias name="string1" alias="string4"/>

    <bean name="testBean" id="testBean" class="somePackage.SomeClass"/>

</beans>
```

Bonus question: Is there a way to create copy of a bean, rather than just passing a reference to the same bean? Something like value="#{string1.clone()}"

Comment: you could make string1 bean prototype, then each bean will have a different instance of the string1

Comment: Can you re-format your document, the element `<bean name="string3" id="string3" value="#{string1}">` does not have a closing tag

Comment: @AndreiSfat, any thoughts on how to make string3 assignment work?

Comment: I answered the `copy of a bean` bit. For what you are trying to do with the assignment for one bean name to another, doesn't really make sense. Are you sure you are not misusing Spring for what you want to accomplish? What is wrong with doing the reference directly?

Comment: @AndreiSfat, "string1" defines a bean that is needed in multiple places.  Except the getBean(name) used is different in different places.  For example, I'm trying to make getBean("string3") get an instance of string1.  And getBean("string4") also gets string1 bean.  Aliasing works, of course.  But it is not as explicit as saying "string3 = string1".  Which seems also less likely to produce duplicates of string3.

Comment: My main concern with the alias statement is that it assigns LHS to RHS, instead of the usual RHS to LHS.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [official Spring 3.x documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-beanname):

You can set as many as identifiers you want for a bean with 2 approaches:

1. Provide as many as identifiers in `name` attribute, separated by a comma (,), semicolon (;), or white space.
2. Using `<alias>`. this approach is useful when you want to point to a bean in another system/subsystem, as it is fully described in documentation:

> Specifying all aliases where the bean is actually defined is not
>   always adequate, however. It is sometimes desirable to introduce an
>   alias for a bean that is defined elsewhere. This is commonly the case
>   in large systems where configuration is split amongst each subsystem,
>   each subsystem having its own set of object definitions. In XML-based
>   configuration metadata, you can use the  element to accomplish
>   this.

So to answer your question, yes, you can do it with `name` attribute

For the bonus question, you need to use [Bean Scopes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes)

Comment: Is there a way to do it with spel, rather than aliases?

Comment: @scorpdaddy what do you mean by SpEL? an specific element that supports SpEL?

Comment: SPring Expression Language, as shown in string3 above.

Comment: Is there an SpEL way to do it?